# How does the amount of memory for a process get determined?

Tags: linux, memory, process, heap-memory, stack-memory

From my understanding, when a process is under execution it has some amount of memory at it's disposal. As the stack increases in size it builds from one end of the process (disregarding global variables that come before the stack), while the heap builds from another end. If you keep adding to the stack or heap, eventually all the memory will be used up for this process.

How does the amount of memory the process is given get determined? I can only imagine it depends on a bunch of different variables, but an as-general-as-possible response would be great. If things have to get specific, I'm interested in linux processes written in C++.

Answer (score 3):

On most platforms you will encounter, Linux runs with virtual memory enabled.  This means that each process has its own virtual address space, the size of which is determined only by the hardware and the way the kernel has configured it.

For example, on the x86 architecture with a "3/1" split configuration, *every* userspace process has 3GB of address space available to it, within which the heap and stack are allocated.  This is regardless of how much *physical* memory is available in the system.  On the x86-64 architecture, 128TB of address space is typically available to each userspace process.

Physical memory is separately allocated to back that virtual memory.  The amount of this available to a process depends upon the configuration of the system, but in general it's simply supplied "on-demand" - limited mostly how much physical memory and swap file space exists, and how much is currently in use for other purposes.

Answer (score -1):

The stack does not magically grow. It's size is static and the size is determined at linking time. So when you take enough space from the stack, it overflows (stack overflow ;)

On the other hand, the heap area 'magically' grows. Meaning that when ever more memory is needed for heap, the program asks operating system for more memory.

EDIT: As Mat pointed out below, the stack actually can increase during runtime on modern operating systems.

Comment: your information about the stack is incorrect. it can grow at runtime (at least on linux), and when it does it's "magic" in the sense that the kernel does that automatically without the process knowing about it/having to call a function. And the heap doesn't "magically" grow, it only grows by explicit calls from the process (malloc/mmap/sbrk/...).

Comment: Yeah you are definitely right about heap, it requires calls from the process. I did wrote that the "program asks" for memory though... But I'm not sure about the stack. I made little test program in C where function calls itself 10M times and it produced seg.fault. (which I assume was because stack overflowed).

Comment: There are stack limits on linux (soft & hard) that can be controlled per session and per process. use `ulimit -s` to display it (in bash) for your current shell, `ulimit -s <somevalue>` to set it (it's inherited by children). System-wide limits are set in `/etc/security/limits.conf`. It can be unlimited. A process can try to increase it's allowable stack space with `setrlimit`. If you manage to get the stack limit to unlimited, your process won't die until all ram is exhausted (and it does not start with an enormous stack segment).

Comment: Thank you Mat for explaining this. It seems I didn't know as much as I though I would.

Comment: Also, there's work being done to allow for non-contiguous stacks - that is, when you run low on stack space, some more memory will be allocated, possibly not adjacent to the old stack, and execution will continue on this new segment. When you return past the point where it was allocated, this segment gets freed automatically.